# XML to dataGridView c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm making my first steps with `XML` and binding data to `DataGridView`
I have a XML file

```
<root>
    <setting id="1">
        <name1>val1</name1>
        <name2>val2</name2>
        <name3>val3</name3>
    </setting>
    <setting id= "2">
        <name1>val1</name1>
        <name2>val2</name2>
        <name3>val3</name3>
    </setting>
    <setting id= "3">

    </setting>
</root>
```

But what I get is

```
name1   name2   name3  
val1    val2    val3
val1    val2    val3
...
```

What I want is

```
name1  val1 
name2  val2  
name3  val3
```

what I did till now is

```
//...
DataGridView1.DataSource = PopulateDataGrid();
//...


    public DataTable PopulateDataGrid()
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(SettingsXMLPath);
        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

when I run the code it makes rows for each  block

what I'm I missing here ?

Comment: Define "rows for each block". What is happening that you didn't expect. What did you think was going to happen?

Comment: lets say I have two Settings Blocks within each of them I have 5 parameters --> I get to 3 rows ( name of params , id1 , id2 ) with 5 columns for each block and only 2 columns ( name , value ) and 5 rows for each <settings>

Comment: Take a look at [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx). That should help you out.

Comment: @Matthijs can you help me out here ? I just cant rap my head around it

Comment: This doesn't really make sense in a logical thinking. Shouldn't all settings under one ID be under the same settings? So ID=1 has 3 values, ID = 2 has 3 values etc..

Comment: @Matthijs yeah you are right I want to be able to choose only one id from the set

Comment: Is it usefull to display the data like that then? I don't get the use. Again. Look into XmlSerialization.

Comment: I want it to be displayed in datagridview in that form , and I've looked in XmlSerialization but I just cant make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file should like something like this to achieve the result you want.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>Name1</Column1>
    <Column2>Value1</Column2>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>Name2</Column1>
    <Column2>Value2</Column2>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>Name3</Column1>
    <Column2>Value3</Column2>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>Name4</Column1>
    <Column2>Value4</Column2>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Is there is way to convert one form of XML to another ?

Comment: What do you mean by one form of XML to another?  I don't know of any built-in conversion tool.  I guess if you want to re-arrange the data you have to do it manually.  The best way will be to fill a DataGridView1 with the original data and then transfer that data to another DataGridView2 in the format you want and then export it to an XML file.

Comment: yeah I thought it would be it ... thanks for clearing it up for me